# MongoDB ERR Connection Refused

Tags: mongodb

After disconnecting from MongoDB and shutting down my PC, whenever I restart my PC and MongoDB, it gives an error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`. I have to repair the installation every single time to make it work and connect normally. How can I fix it? I am using Windows 11 23H2.

Code I am using to connect to MongoDB through Node.js:

```
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("proj"));

// MongoDB connection configuration
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const dbName = "database"; 
const client = new MongoClient(mongoURI);

async function connectToMongoDB() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", err);
  }
}

// Connect to MongoDB
connectToMongoDB();
```

Comment: Are you sure the MongoDB service is set to start-up automatically after a reboot?

Comment: I am using the GUI MongoDB Compass. It is set to auto-start on boot. I checked it in services.msc.

Comment: _"it gives an error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`"_ - where are you seeing this error?

Comment: You set the service to auto-start but did you also check whether it is running?

Comment: the error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` shows up in my terminal when I attempt to connect with MongoDB using Node.js connect - @prasad_

Yes, I ensured that the service auto starts and it is running. - @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: _"the error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 shows up in my terminal when I attempt to connect with MongoDB using Node.js connect"_ In that case please include the code you are trying (you can edit your question post). Also, you can refer the MongoDB NodeJS Driver documentation for example connection code, [Connect to MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/connect-to-mongodb/). Also, see [Connection Troubleshooting Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/connection-troubleshooting/).

Comment: Yes, I have added the code I am using to initialize the connection.

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means the client application was able to connect to the noted IP address, but the machine at that address did not have any process listening on that IP:Port.  This could be a mismatch between "localhost" resolving to "127.0.0.1" vs "::1".  From a command prompt, run `netstat -aon | find "27017"` so see if anything is listening.

Comment: Thanks for that. Was able to figure it out and fix it. It works normally now.